# Getting Error Popup on frontend Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, frontend-error

**some time show popup error on screen..**

Getting Error Popup on frontend Magento 2.3.1

[image]

Comment: Please try to be more specific, BTW this looks like an alert on mobile mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error alert popup related to justuno magento 2 extension in
>   magexsync.js file when Ajax request failed.

```
alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
```

> just commit out this above line of code